# Is this logic correct regarding how standard deviations work with a simple game example?

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

Say we have a game where you start at 0 points, you are allowed to get negative points per round and allowed to have negative total points. The points you earn each round is on average 1 with a standard deviation of 1. After 10 rounds, the expected value for the number of points you will earn is 10, but I want to know the odds that the player will have below 0 points after 10 rounds.

How I did it was first by finding the standard deviation of the 10 trials, which I believe is $10^.5$. Thus, 0 is about 3.16 standard deviations away from the mean, and from there I can simply find the probability. Is this the correct logic?

Comment: What is the distribution of points earned per round?

Comment: There's no way to give a definitive answer. Depending on the shape of the distribution of points earned per round the answer could be very low ($\to$ 0) or it could be quite high.

Comment: Points per round is normally distributed with mean of 1 and standard deviation of 1, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one-sided Chebyshev inequality to bound the probability. One version is $$P[X \lt \mu - k \sigma ] \lt \frac{1}{k^2 + 1}  $$

With $k= \sqrt{10},$ the probability is less than $\frac{1}{11}$.